# fontspec \setmainfont over-rides href color

Tags: hyperref, color, fontspec

I'm happy with the way fontspec is working for me, but have one problem.  I have the command:
`\setmainfont[Color=393939]{URW Palladio L}`
which colors all the text in my document.  I have darker greys for headings.

The problem is that I want all hyperlinks to be automatically colored with the color of my choice. I use 
`\usepackage{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{...urlcolor=orange}`

Coloring hyperlinks like this works fine if I do *not* have the `\setmainfont[Color=393939]{URW Palladio L}` command, but it does not work when it is included.

Is there a way I can color all body text and also automatically color hyperlinks?

Kit

Comment: Oddly enough, the correct colour is maintained with `\url` links, just not with `\href` links.

Comment: The coloring by hyperref relies on the `\color` macro, which is overridden by the color specification for the font. URL work because they use a different font.

Comment: So the solution would be to "trick" xetex into thinking the hrefs are a different font. Any ideas how that might work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Building again on Alan's answer, this seems to work (even better), so long as the color has been defined beforehand or it's predefined:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{1,0.3,0.5}

\setmainfont[Color=FF0000]{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont[Color=00FF00]{Linux Biolinum O}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,urlcolor=mycolor,filecolor=orange}
\makeatletter
\def\HyColor@@@@UseColor#1\@nil{\addfontfeatures{Color=#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

A hyperlink:
\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com}{TeX StackExchange}

\sffamily A hyperlink:
\href{abc}{TeX StackExchange}
\end{document}
```

You'll notice that the second hyperlink is colored differently because it's not a URL and `filecolor` is used.

Comment: Nicer. :-)  I didn't hunt hard enough into `hycolor.sty`.

Comment: Thank you so much for all this support.  I don't even understand what you're doing.  Regardless, it is not working for me, the same problem as above (hyperlinks coming out black, but I do have the red and green colours working _before_ the links).  I must be doing something very basic wrong here.

Comment: Working now that I have up-to-date texlive.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Building on Seamus' suggestion in the comments (and edited to include egreg's suggestion) into an answer, here's what seems like a solution:

I  redefine the relevant part of the `\href` command to add the orange colour in the links. I've left the `urlcolor` in the `\hypersetup` command to get the color for plain `\url` links.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setmainfont[Color=393939]{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,urlcolor=orange}
\makeatletter
\def\Hy@href#{%
  \addfontfeatures{Color=orange}\hyper@normalise\href@
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
A hyperlink:
\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com}{TeX StackExchange}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Nice. However, simply writing `\addfontfeatures{Color=orange}` instead of `\hreffont` seems to work the same; it doesn't require a new font family and works also in a "sans serif" context. One should probably act where `urlcolor=` does its business.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, using `\addfontfeatures` is a better way to go.  I've updated my answer.  Your answer is even more general, though.

Comment: @Alan, actually defining a separate font might be a wiser choice (IIRC, `\addfontfeatures` defines a new font behind the scenes *each* time it is invoked, which can be expensive resources-wise).

Comment: @Khaled That was my understanding too, which was why I originally had `\newfontfamily`. So is there a non-expensive way to add the colour which will work for both `\sffamiy` and `rmfamily` (which is what motivated egreg's suggestion)?

Comment: This looks great.  I don't know why though, but I can't make it work on my machine.  I copied and pasted your code directly to a blank file, ran xelatex on that file, and opened the resulting pdf.  The hyperlink text is not nice and orange like yours, but _black_.  The only way I can get it to go orange is by commenting out the line `\setmainfont[Color=393939]{Linux Libertine O}`.  What's going wrong?

Comment: @oldmankit What version of `hyperref` are you using? Mine is 6.82g (2011/04/17). (Put \listfiles in your preamble to see what versions of the packages are loaded (the list will appear in the log file (or the console output.)))

Comment: @Alan Munn, thank you. 2009/10/09 v6.79a.  That looks horribly old.  Let me work out how to update that.

Comment: @alan-munn It's taken me a week to update that package because doing so broke several others.  Finally got there:  hyperref.sty    2011/04/09 v6.82f       But still no coloured links! : (

Comment: @oldmankit Did you update your whole distribution or just parts of it?  If the latter, this may be the cause of your problem.

Comment: @alan-munn Just parts of it.  I couldn't find a way to update all of it.  I posted in the Ubuntu forums but didn't any replies.  I'll go back there to find a way to get it all updated properly.

Comment: @oldmankit Try the answers to this question here: [Vanilla TeXLive on Debian or Unbuntu](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/2693)

Comment: @alan-munn Thanks very much for the link.  I can see it will be quite a job, since Ubuntu uses an outdated texlive version, and there may be conflicts and broken dependencies, and also it needs more bandwidth than my mobile phone Edge connection will allow.  I'll have to wait until I get somewhere with broadband...!

Comment: Finally, done!  I got the entire texlive 2011 through bit torrent; it took several nights to download it.  I've installed it and it's all working now.  Wonderful!

Comment: @oldmankit I'm glad it's all working now.