# Can't apply color inside fancyfoot, setmainfont overwrites it

Tags: color, fontspec, fancyhdr

I'm using `fancyhdr` package and have this **tex** file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{testcv}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\footersection{\today}{Footer text}{}

\begin{document}
Page text
\end{document}
```

And this class file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{testcv}[2016/02/10 CV class]

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}} 
\ProcessOptions

\LoadClass[titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancyhfoffset{0em}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}


\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{contentcolor}{HTML}{A6A6A6}
\definecolor{footercolor}{HTML}{FF0000}

% (1) Footer color == contentcolor
\setmainfont[Color=contentcolor, Path = ../fonts/ubuntu/]{Ubuntu-L}

% (2) Footer color is ok
% \setmainfont[Path = ../fonts/ubuntu/]{Ubuntu-L} 


\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\def\footrule{{
  \vskip-\footruleskip\vskip-\footrulewidth
  \color{footercolor}
  \hrule\@width\headwidth\@height
  \footrulewidth\vskip\footruleskip
}}


\newcommand{\footersection}[3]{
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[L]{\color{footercolor}#1}
\fancyfoot[C]{\color{footercolor}#2}
\fancyfoot[R]{\color{footercolor}#3}   
}
```

With (1) uncommented I have this output with wrong color:
[image: wrong color]

If we use (2) instead then page text color is black, but footer works ok:
[image: good color]

Compiling with XeLaTeX on Windows.

How can I set `\setmainfont[Color=contentcolor]` and have correct red footer?

Already found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22026/fontspec-setmainfont-over-rides-href-color), but i can't use it.

Comment: You can setup a dedicated font for the footer, something like `\newfontfamily\footerfontfamily[Color=footercolor, Path = ../fonts/ubuntu/]{Ubuntu-L}` and then use `\footerfontfamily` in the footer.

Comment: Thank you, this does the job, but I need to know why this happend and how to fix it other way.

Comment: When you are using the `Color`-key in \setmainfont, this color always wins, you no longer can change it with the \color command. (`\addfontfeature{Color=green}Green` should work, but I normally avoid to use `\addfontfeature` to often).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) notice, when you are using the **Color**-key in `\setmainfont`, this color always wins, you no longer can change it with the `\color` command. My document was based on popular [Deedy Resume](https://github.com/deedy/Deedy-Resume) and correct solution was:

```
\newcommand{\footeritem}[1]{
  \color{footercolor}
  \fontspec[Path = ../fonts/ubuntu/]{Ubuntu-L}  
  \selectfont{#1}
}

\newcommand{\footersection}[3]{
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[L]{\footeritem{#1}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\footeritem{#2}}
\fancyfoot[R]{\footeritem{#3}}
}
```