# LaTex CV- Deedy Resume: How to change the color of bullet point items?

Tags: xetex

I'm working on modifying the Deedy CV template ([link here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/deedy-cv/bjryvfsjdyxz#.U2H9Kq1dV18)). I would like to change the color  of the bullet point items to black. I've tried adding `color{black}` in:

```
\begin{tightemize}
\color{black}
\item 52 out of 2500 applicants chosen to be a KPCB Fellow 2014.
\item Led and shipped Yoda - the admin interface for the new Phoenix platform. 
\item Full-stack developer - Wrote and reviewed code...
\end{tightemize}
\sectionsep
```

but it doesn't work. Anyone know how I can change the text color to black?
[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please give a fully compilable code.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by Ulrike Fischer in a comment on [Can't apply color inside fancyfoot, setmainfont overwrites it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318384/cant-apply-color-inside-fancyfoot-setmainfont-overwrites-it), the issue is that the class sets the color in the main font loading command (`\setmainfont`), and that takes precedence over any color settings in the document itself. Also noted there is a solution, i.e., define a new font family with a different color and use that in the environment where you want to change the column.

In the code snippet below the original font declaration from Deedy Resume is copied from the class file and used for a new font family with color blue, just to illustrate the effect.

To apply this font family the `tightemize` is redefined by copying the original definition from the class file and adding `\itemfontfamily` at the start.

Code:

```
\documentclass[]{deedy-resume-openfont}
% define font family
\newfontfamily\itemfontfamily[Color=blue, Path = fonts/lato/,BoldItalicFont=Lato-RegIta,BoldFont=Lato-Reg,ItalicFont=Lato-LigIta]{Lato-Lig}
% redefine tightemize environment to use the new font family
\renewenvironment{tightemize}{%
\itemfontfamily%
\vspace{-\topsep}\begin{itemize}\itemsep1pt \parskip0pt \parsep0pt}
{\end{itemize}\vspace{-\topsep}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
 
\begin{document}
```

Result:

[image]